# Increase size of number field in html

Tags: html

I am trying to increase the box to fit the required placeholder text. If I change input type from "number" to "text" it works but I want to use "number" so I can specify the range.

```
    <form action="Program3.php" method="post">
    <p>Distance (in miles): 
    <input style="height:200px;font-size:14pt;">
    <input type="number" name="distance" required
    size="100" min="300" max="600"
    required placeholder="Enter a number between 300 & 600">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the width with CSS:

```html
<input type="number" name="distance" required
style="width:20em" min="300" max="600"
required placeholder="Enter a number between 300 & 600">
```

Comment: ok that worked perfectly. How do I change the color of the font of that required text?

Comment: don't use pixel sizes to control text field sizing. at least use typographic units, like `em`. e.g. if OP's blind and running with a 500pt font, 210px will show only a tiny bit of one charcter.

Comment: @Rhett With CSS again. `color:red`.

Comment: @Rhett Please don't forget to accept my answer in five minutes.

Comment: Although I agree a user should always accept an answer, (s)he should *never* be told which answer to accept. It's up to them to choose which answer eventually helped them out the most.

Comment: @ice So true! But let me be naughty.

Answer (score 0):

A more elegant solution would be to use Javascript. This will automaticly set all your input fields to the width of the placeholders:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
 var input = document.querySelectorAll('input');
 for(i=0; i<input.length; i++){
  input[i].setAttribute('size',input[i].getAttribute('placeholder').length);
 }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="A very long placeholder." /><br />
<input type="text" placeholder="A short one." />
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to show a lengthy text as placeholder so u have to increase width of input field not tha height.

```
 Style="width:300px"
```